# Getting KeyError: '[ 1.4 nan nan 1.83] not in index'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm wanting to add values like my desired output below.

I am using:

```
#O1 Mangoes
aa = df2.AD=np.where(df3.AL.isin(df1.EW),df2.AD,np.nan)

df3['O1'] = df1[aa]

#O2 Curries
zz = df1.WE=np.where(df3.AL.isin(df1.EW),df1.WE,np.nan)
print(zz)
df3['O2'] = df1[zz]
```

I keep getting:

```
KeyError: '[ 1.4    nan   nan  1.83] not in index'
```

Everything is correct aside from I want to transfer this to column O1 and O2 as well as drop NaN

I have tried to use: `df = df3[pd.notnull(df3['TN'])]` and write to this to excel but my output looks like:

[image]

df1

```
                                        EW    WE           DA
0  Persebaya Surabaya v PS Mojokerto Putra  1.40  https://www
1                                JP Voltes  3.40  https://www
2                                  pp v pp  3.10  https://www
3                                    Gagra  1.83  https://www
```

df2

```
            AA                  AB                  AC     AD            AE
0  Today 18:00  Persebaya Surabaya  PS Mojokerto Putra   1.95  https://www.
1  Today 18:00    Davao Aguilas FC           JP Voltes   1.95  https://www.
2  Today 18:30     Adelaide United              Sydney   1.66  https://www.
3  Today 20:00                  pp                  pp  16.00  https://www.
```

Desired (I get this already, save for changing to column O)

```
           DAT                                        G  \
0  Today 18:00  Persebaya Surabaya v PS Mojokerto Putra   
1  Today 18:00             Davao Aguilas FC v JP Voltes   
2  Today 18:30                 Adelaide United v Sydney   
3  Today 20:00                                  pp v pp   

                                        TN   O1            L1  \
0  Persebaya Surabaya v PS Mojokerto Putra  1.4  https://www.   
1                                      NaN  NaN  https://www.   
2                                      NaN  NaN  https://www.   
3                                  pp v pp  3.10  https://www.   

                                       TN2   O2           L2    D   AJ  \
0  Persebaya Surabaya v PS Mojokerto Putra  1.95  https://www  NaN  NaN   
1                                      NaN  NaN  https://www  NaN  NaN   
2                                      NaN  NaN  https://www  NaN  NaN   
3                                  pp v pp  16  https://www  NaN  NaN   

                                        AK  
0  Persebaya Surabaya v PS Mojokerto Putra  
1                                      NaN  
2                                      NaN  
3                                  pp v pp
```

Full [code](http://textuploader.com/dqv7r)

Code of interest:

```
##O  <-- Get value beside T

    cs = df2[df2.AD.isin(df1.EW)]
    df3 = df3[['AJ','AK']]
    print (cs)
```

Comment: Do you need `df2[df2.AD.isin(df1.WE)]` ? check `AD` column by `WE` ?

Comment: Also it is not clear your expected output, is possible create it from your input data in question?

Comment: @jezrael  This gives error when changing it to a column O1  aa = df2.AD=np.where(df3.AL.isin(df1.EW),df2.AD,np.nan)

df3['O1'] = df1[aa].  Gives: KeyError: '[  1.95    nan    nan  16.  ] not in certain column

Comment: Hmmm, maybe need `df3['O1'] = aa`

Comment: @jezrael Is there way to get my expected output in excel rather than gaps

Comment: Hmm, in excel instead `NaN`s get empty cells, but not sure with your expected output, because output is not input data in question only.

Comment: @jezrael UH wait that works fine actually.  Aside from df3['D'] = df3['O2'] - df3['O1'] gives blank.  http://textuploader.com/dqv2t  .  Try to find Difference hence name "D" :)

Comment: Because NaNs I guess. Need `df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fillna=0) `

Comment: @jezrael My output looks like: https://ibb.co/mkKJKb and I get: keyword argument 'fillna'

Comment: Sorry, my typo `df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0) `

Comment: @jezrael Seems to be issue of getting this to the excel or somewhere along line its not working. https://pastebin.com/BcTrJSN6

Comment: What is `print (df3.dtypes)` ?

Comment: @jezrael You can see in code that the difference is there but then some part of script makes it disappear.  Here is my output of print (df3.dtypes) https://pastebin.com/kXsQ47xE

Comment: It should working nice, because `float64` for both `O` columns.

Comment: @jezrael Is there different way of finding difference that might work? HMM

Comment: Not idea, I guess there has tobe something wrong.

Comment: because `df3['D'] = df3['O2'] - df3['O1']` should working perfectly if no NaNs values and floats.

Comment: @jezrael Strange.  Still showing NaN xD.  I tried a different column.  Reset workbook too.

Comment: Is possible share your excel file?

Comment: @jezrael Figured it out I think.  df3.to_excel(writer, startcol=0).  I had: df.to_excel(writer, startcol=0) so I it did not copy over D.  Hmm is there a way to remove 
0
1
2
3
and well as header name AJ

Comment: `df3.to_excel(writer, header=None)` or `df3.to_excel(writer, header=False)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I had df instead of df3 xD

Comment: Yes, I think there has to be some typo ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160484/discussion-between-jezrael-and-jytinjalmon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keyerror error means there are not columns with this names.

Also there is necessary same length of all dataframes and same index value, if want assign column from `df3` to `df2` or `df1`.

```
df2.AD = np.where(df3.AL.isin(df1.EW),df2.AD,np.nan)
#if want assign one column to another
df3['O1'] = df2.AD
```

Comment: Hmm.. don't suppose you know how to get around ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (93,) (164,) () https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653865/i-keep-getting-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes.

Comment: I check it and there is unclear what need. There is no df3, so is unclear what need. But I guess there is necessary merge, because different sizes of dataframes, then get `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together`.

Comment: I see.  So there is no command to make it the same size to get around it?  My full code is here if useful https://pastebin.com/UdtHtbfn

Comment: I have main problem. What do you need? because it depends on it. E.g. you have 5 csv files and need join them together? Or something else?

Comment: I have 2 csv files which is scraped data.  I think thats why it throws errors but surely you can get around this error and use data.  I can send you files if you want.

Comment: Super, I have meail in my profile, is possible send me 3 files and desired output, e.g. first 10 rows?

Comment: Because `np.where` working nice, but there is necessary same size of data. And how I can get it? remove rows? From start, from end, which rows? So I guess you need something else, so I think real data with desired ouptut should help. thanks.

Comment: Sent you the files :)

Comment: I've posted a new question with hopefully enough detail so others can replicate.  It seems the script works all but for scraped data.. or maybe I'm missing something.  I hope I do not have to resort to VBA... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658860/pandas-scraped-data-not-working-in-pandas