# Scraped CSV pandas dataframe I get: ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I run below code and get:

```
raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
```

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

for:

```
print(df3)
zz = df1.WE=np.where(df1.EW.isin(df3.AL),df1.WE,np.nan)
df3['O2'] = zz  #Error Line
```

I have got this to work for data in a csv that has identical column structure save for this is scraped data where as the other csv was created manually.

df1

```
                                                 EW      WE  \
0                                            can v can   1.900   
1                       Lanus U20 v Argentinos Jrs U20   2.100   

                                                    DA  
0    https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...  
1    https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...
```

df2

```
                AA                      AB                       AC      AD  \
0      Today 19:00           Indonesia U23           Kyrgyzstan U23  650.00   
1      Today 23:00   Brunei Darussalam U23             Mongolia U23    3.30   
2      Today 19:30                     can                      can  110.00     

                                                   AE  
0   https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
1   https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
2   https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...
```

df3

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DAT', 'G', 'TN', 'O1', 'L1', 'TN2', 'O2', 'L2', 'D', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL'])
```

Desired:

df3:

```
               DAT                      G  \
0      Today 19:00                 can v can   


         TN                           O1  \
0   can v can                        1.900   

                         L1  \
0   https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...   

        TN2                         O2  \
0   can v can                       110.00


                                                   L2    D     
0   https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  108.1
```

Code:

```
   import pandas as pd
    import time
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    print('####CURRIES###')
    df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\O\\df1.csv',
                       index_col=False,
                       usecols=[0,1,2],
                       names=["EW", "WE", "DA"],
                       header=None)
    print(df1)

    print('####Mangoes###')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\O\\df2.csv',
                       index_col=False,
                       usecols=[0,1,2, 3, 4],
                       names=["AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE"],
                       header=None)
    print(df2)

    df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DAT', 'G', 'TN', 'O1', 'L1', 'TN2', 'O2', 'L2', 'D', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL'])

    df3['DAT'] = df2['AA']








    df3['G'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']

    df3['AK'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']
    df3['AL'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']


    print(df3)



    #TN

    print('Vlookup')
    aa = df3.AK=np.where(df3.AK.isin(df1.EW),df3.AK,np.nan)
    print(aa)
    df3['TN'] = aa

    print('Vlookup output')
    print(df3)
    ## Not working

    #TN

    print('Vlookup')
    aa = df3.AK=np.where(df3.AK.isin(df1.EW),df3.AK,np.nan)
    print(aa)
    df3['TN2'] = aa
    ## Not working

    #L
    df3['L1'] = df2['AE']
    df3['L2'] = df1['DA']

    print('dataframe complete')
    print(df3)
    ##O  <-- Get value beside T




    print('done')

    #O1 Mangoes
    aa = df2.AD=np.where(df3.AL.isin(df1.EW),df2.AD,np.nan)

    df3['O1'] = aa


    #O2 Curries
    #zz = df1.WE=np.where(df3.AL.isin(df1.EW),df1.WE,np.nan)

    #zz = df1.WE=np.where(df1.EW.isin(df3.AL),df1.WE,np.nan)

    ###############ERROR B#  ###############ERROR B#

    print(df3)
    zz = df1.WE=np.where(df1.EW.isin(df3.AL),df1.WE,np.nan)
    df3['O2'] = zz


###############ERROR ABOVE#
    print('output')
    df = df3[pd.notnull(df3['TN'])]

    #df3['D'] = df3['O2'] - df3['O1']



    print('tt')
    #df3.dropna(how='all')
    #df3.columns = df3.columns.droplevel(3)
    print(df3)
    #df3['AA'] = df1[zz]

    print('zza')
    df3.pop('AK')
    df3.pop('AL')

    df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0)
    df3.pop('AJ')

    print(df3.dtypes)
    NaNs = df3 = df3.dropna(subset=['O1','O2'])
    print(NaNs)
    import pandas as pd

    print('test')
    print(df3)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\O\\dx.xlsx')
    df3.to_excel(writer, startcol=0, index = False) 
    writer.save()
    print(df3)


    #df3.pop('AK')

    #df3['T1'] = df1[zz]

    #Delete Columns
    #put O in a column value
    #
```

Scraping code to create dataframes [here](https://pastebin.com/TYLwzxAJ) .

I then write can v can in df1 column A row 1.

I then write can in df2 Column B row 3

I then write can in df2 column C row 3

Or simply here are exact files (scraped) I am using.

[df1](https://dropfile.to/j77PNy0)

[df2](https://dropfile.to/Y8qO5CT)

These files below the code above works perfectly.  I don't understand why it is not working for scraped data.

Working [code](https://pastebin.com/MNk2cSzV)

[df2](https://dropfile.to/Ja4MMur)

[df1](https://dropfile.to/exk4doy)

Comment: put data instead of links to files.

Comment: @furas The dataframes is included in question.  I just included files in case data dependent problem I am missing.

Comment: I see here 2 main problems. Why is empty `df3`, with only columns? And for testing need different number of rows, e.g. in first file 4 and in second file 3 rows. Then it simulate real data more real.

Comment: @jezrael df3 is empty as its the new dataframe I'm wanting to build from df2 and 1.  My dataset current looks like: https://ibb.co/hOF84b AND https://pastebin.com/CFMiL4ec . Slightly better but not yet what I want

Comment: @jezrael For a simpler example I have created: https://pastebin.com/VUF7xMxV

Comment: It seems good , let me time for test.

Comment: @jezrael Any luck? I feel its hard for others to reproduce without using a lot of my code and that makes for lengthy read.

Comment: I test it and now I am in `df1.WE=np.where(df1.EW.isin(df3.AL),df1.WE,np.nan)`. this working fine, overwrite column `WE` in `df1`. But then is problem. `df1` have `174` rows and `df3` have `40` rows. So impossible assign like `df3['O2'] = pd.Series(za)`. Maybe need `df3.O2=np.where(df3.AL.isin(df1.EW),df2.AD,np.nan)`, (it is same like above, but data are changed in `df1.WE`, because `za=  df1.WE=np.where(df1.EW.isin(df3.AL),df1.WE,np.nan)`)

Comment: @jezrael That worked though I am getting 0 for difference now. za = df3.O2=np.where(df3.AL.isin(df1.EW),df2.AD,np.nan)
df3['O2'] = pd.Series(za)

df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'])
print(df3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160567/discussion-between-jezrael-and-jytinjalmon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with `inner join`:

```
print('####CURRIES###')
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\O\\df1.csv',
                   index_col=False,
                   usecols=[0,1,2],
                   names=["EW", "WE", "DA"],
                   header=None)
print(df1.head())
####CURRIES###
                                 EW    WE  \
0                         can v can  1.90   
1    Lanus U20 v Argentinos Jrs U20  2.10   
2      Botafogo RJ U20 v Toluca U20  1.83   
3  Atletico Mineiro U20 v Bahia U20  2.10   
4                 FC Porto v Monaco  1.36   

                                                  DA  
0  https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...  
1  https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...  
2  https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...  
3  https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...  
4  https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...  

print('####Mangoes###')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\O\\df2.csv',
                   index_col=False,
                   usecols=[0,1,2, 3, 4],
                   names=["AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE"],
                   header=None)
```

---

```
print(df2.head())
####Mangoes###
            AA                     AB                      AC      AD  \
0  Today 19:00          Indonesia U23          Kyrgyzstan U23  650.00   
1  Today 23:00  Brunei Darussalam U23            Mongolia U23    3.30   
2  Today 19:30                    can                     can  110.00   
3  Today 20:00  FC Zbrojovka Brno U19       Sparta Prague U19    1.97   
4  Today 20:30         Rahmatgonj MFS  Sheikh Jamal Dhanmondi    1.51   

                                                  AE  
0  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
1  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
2  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
3  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...  
4  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...
```

---

```
#crewte new column called EW in df2
df2['EW'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']   
#merge on columns EW  
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='EW')
#change columns names
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'WE':'O1','AD':'O2'})
#subtract O columns
df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0)
print (df3)
            AA             AB              AC     O2  \
0  Today 19:00  Indonesia U23  Kyrgyzstan U23  650.0   
1  Today 19:30            can             can  110.0   

                                                  AE  \
0  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...   
1  https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/footb...   

                               EW   O1  \
0  Indonesia U23 v Kyrgyzstan U23  2.0   
1                       can v can  1.9   

                                                  DA      D  
0  https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...  648.0  
1  https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E40/F...  108.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
df3['O2'] = pd.Series(za)
```

Not a scraping problem at all upon investigation with isolated python script and simplified.