# How do I hide all excluding a file type

Tags: python, file, operating-system, hide, glob

I'm trying to hide all my files excluding [.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7i9G.png).

**Below hides**: files, exe

Does not hide: folders

**I want**: Hide folders, files

Does not hide: .exe

```
import os, shutil
import ctypes
folder = 'C:\\Users\\TestingAZ1'
for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(file_path, 2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I cannot use -onefile due to large size for each exe.

Comment: This is incredibly confusing. Can you limit this question to the issue you're encountering and remove everything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it ;)

```
import os
import ctypes

folder = 'C:\\Users\\TestingAZ1'

for item_name in os.listdir(folder):

    item_path = os.path.join(folder, item_name)

    try:

        if os.path.isfile(item_path) and not item_name.lower().endswith('.exe'):
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(item_path, 2)
        elif os.path.isdir(item_path) and item_name not in ['.', '..']:
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(item_path, 2)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Looking at the documentation of `SetFileAttributesW`, it can be used for folders as well. Which leave some "filtering". If your item is a file, you do not want to hide it if it ends on ".exe" or ".EXE". If it's a folder, you do not want to hide it if it is the folder you're in or its parent.